Minimize sum of two numbers given their product is constant
Suppose that two numbers have constant product $a\cdot b=C=\textrm{const}$. When does the sum $S(a,b):=a+b$ become minimal?

My idea is to first assume that $C\neq 0$, and to use $b=\frac{C}{a}$ to rewrite
$$
S(a,b)=a+\frac{C}{a}=:f(a)
$$
and to minimize this function. Its first and second derivatives are, respectively,
$$
f'(a)=1-\frac{C}{a^2},\qquad f''(a)=2\frac{C}{a^3}.
$$
Moreover,
$$
f'(a)=0\qquad \Leftrightarrow\qquad a_1=\sqrt{C}, a_2=-\sqrt{C},
$$
so it remains to check whether $f''(a_{1,2})>0$ in order to have minima.
Case 1: $C>0$. This means that either $a,b>0$ or $a,b<0$:

Case 1.1: $a,b>0$. In this case, we have $f''(a)>0$, which means that $a=a_1=\sqrt{C}$ is a minimum and $b=\sqrt{C}$.

Case 1.2: $a,b<0$. In this case, $f''(a)<0$, meaning that we do not have a minimum but only a maximum, namely $a=a_2=-\sqrt{C}$ with $b=-\sqrt{C}$.


Case 2: $C<0$. In this situation, we have $f'(a)>1$ so that there are no extreme values at all.
It remains to consider the case $C=0$ and I am not absolutely sure how to do so. I think the following argument works (not making any use of the derivatives):
Claim: For $c=0$ there is no minimum. Since suppose $C=0$. This means that $a=0$ or $b=0$.



Suppose $a=0, b\neq 0$. Then, suppose $a$ and $b$ do minimize the sum $a+b=0+b=b$. But we can choose any $b'<b$ to see that $a\cdot b'=0$ but $a+b'=b'<b=a+b$. So this gives a contradiction.




Same for $a\neq 0$ and $b=0$.




Suppose $a=b=0$. Same argument: Choose any $a'<0$, then $a'\cdot b=0$ but $a'+b=a'<a+b=0$.



So in essence what I am trying to express is:
For each pair $(a,b)$ with $a\cdot b=0$ one always finds a pair $(a',b')$ with $a'\cdot b'=0$ and $a'+b'< a +b$. So that there cannot exist a pair $(a,b)$ with $a\cdot b=0$ which minimizes $a+b$.
Is that okay?
If not: How to treat the case $C=0$?

For $~c = 0,~$ consider $~a = -1,000,000,000~$ and $~b = 0.$

So you are saying that I can choose $a$ arbitrary small?

Why not?.......

I was just wondering if that isn't what I already wrote in my own attempt.

Initially, I didn't read your posting that carefully. I agree that this is what you already wrote.
